# conda --version No module named 'importlib.readers'

Tags: anaconda

I download Anaconda3-2023.03-1-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg from the official website. After the installation is complete, I try `conda --version` and got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.readers'`.

How to solve this error?